# I want to filter an array but the filter function doesn't respond well

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to filter my array with several elements but it turns out the `.filter` does not work, the value that `filterInDeep` returns works but the `.filter()` of `applyfilter()` does not take into account the return:

```
const maquettesListRef = [
    {
        "idMaquette": 1,
        "codeMaquette": "gsgrcs001",
        
        "version": {
            "idVersion": 3,
            "versionG2s": "202110"
        },
        "context": {
            "idContext": 1,
            "libelle": "TP"
        },
        "application": {
            "idApplication": 1,
            "libelle": "nova",

        },
        "baseTemplate": {
            "idBaseTemplate": 1,
            "code": "base_template1",

            "gabarit": {
                "idGabarit": 1,
                "code": "gabarit1",

            }
        },
        "secteur": {
            "idSecteur": 9,
            "libelle": "Prévoyance collective",
            "lstEnfant": []
        },
        "provenance": ""
    },
    {
        "idMaquette": 3,
        "codeMaquette": "gsgrcs002",
        "version": {
            "idVersion": 2,
            "versionG2s": "202107"
        },
        "context": {
            "idContext": 2,
            "libelle": "BATCH"
        },
        "application": {
            "idApplication": 2,

        },
        "baseTemplate": {
            "idBaseTemplate": 1,
            "code": "base_template1",

            "gabarit": {
                "idGabarit": 1,
                "code": "gabarit1",

            }
        },
        "secteur": {
            "idSecteur": 8,
        },
        "provenance": ""
    },
    {
        "idMaquette": 4,
        "codeMaquette": "gsgrcs003",
        "version": {
            "idVersion": 2,
            "versionG2s": "202107"
        },
        "context": {
            "idContext": 3,
            "libelle": "TP/BATCH"
        },
        "application": {
            "idApplication": 2,
        },
        "baseTemplate": {
            "idBaseTemplate": 1,
            "code": "base_template1",

            "gabarit": {
                "idGabarit": 1,
                "code": "gabarit1",

            }
        },
        "secteur": {
            "idSecteur": 8,
            "libelle": "souscription Vie Individuelle",
            "lstEnfant": []
        },
        "provenance": ""
    }
]
```

```json
const filter = {
    "codeMaquette": "g",
    "version": {
        "idVersion": 1
    }
}
```

First call to `applyFilter()` function

my `filtreEnProfondeur` function works it returns me the value `true` or `false` at the right time, but at the time of the callback this one no longer responds and does not return the expected array.

```js
  filterInDeep(object:any,filtre:any){
    return Object.keys(filtre).every((c) =>{
      switch (typeof filtre[c]){
        case "string":
          return (object[c].includes(filtre[c]))
        case "number":
          return (object[c] == filtre[c])
        case "object":
          this.filterInDeep(object[c],filtre[c])
      }
    })
  }


  applyFilter(filter: any) {
  console.log(this.maquettesListRef)
    console.log(filter)
    console.log(this.maquettesListRef.filter((maquette) =>{
      this.filtreEnProfondeur(maquette,filter)
    }))
}
```

Actual `return`

```
[]
```

Expected return

```json
[
    {
        "idMaquette": 1,
        "codeMaquette": "gsgrcs001",
        
        "version": {
            "idVersion": 3,
            "versionG2s": "202110"
        },
        "context": {
            "idContext": 1,
            "libelle": "TP"
        },
        "application": {
            "idApplication": 1,
            "libelle": "nova",

        },
        "baseTemplate": {
            "idBaseTemplate": 1,
            "code": "base_template1",

            "gabarit": {
                "idGabarit": 1,
                "code": "gabarit1",

            }
        },
        "secteur": {
            "idSecteur": 9,
            "libelle": "Prévoyance collective",
            "lstEnfant": []
        },
        "provenance": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: Please may you share what it does return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for you since you need to return bool from `filter` in each call. and since you use `{ }` you don't return anything. Try use `return`:

```
applyFilter(filter: any) {
  console.log(this.maquettesListRef)
  console.log(filter)
  console.log(
    this.maquettesListRef.filter((maquette) => {
      return this.filtreEnProfondeur(maquette,filter)
    })
  )
```

here's a simplified example that demonstrate your problem and the solution for it:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(arr.filter(v => {
  v % 2 == 0
}))
console.log(arr.filter(v => {
  return v % 2 == 0
}))
```